# operations counting insertion bubble selection

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is with my code, Im getting an absurdly large number of operations for my insertion sort code. Was hoping for some help.

```
int insertionSort(int arr[], int n, int &operations)
{
    clock_t start = clock(); 
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
            operations++;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    clock_t end = clock(); 
    return end - start;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set `operations=0` before looping?  Right now, you're just adding to whatever value `operations` had when the function was called, which could have been anything.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this post :[How to count comparisons and swaps in insertion sort? (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127062/how-to-count-comparisons-and-swaps-in-insertion-sort-java)

You can count the number of operations as:

```
long int operations=0;
int insertionSort(int arr[], int n, int &operations)
{
    clock_t start = clock(); 
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while (1)
        {   
            operations++;
            if((j>=0) && (arr[j]>key)){
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j = j - 1;
             }
            else break;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    clock_t end = clock(); 
    return end - start;
}
```

Comment: And if `operations` came in with an absurd number, your solution won't work.  There is no indication that `operations` was initialized outside the function.

Comment: Changes made as per @PaulMcKenzie 's comment. Thank you.